# How to reliably get row index in JTable from MouseEvent?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How can I find out which row in a JTable the user just clicked?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this:

`aJTable.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());`

Answer (score 13):

If you only ever care about listening to selections on the JTable:

```
jTable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        int sel = jTable.getSelectedRow();
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this still work if it's in column or cell selection mode?

Comment: It should, but it also allows to more more with in reaction to the click. The "answer" will need some kind of listener so you know when to read the value.